# setTimeout triggers right away

Tags: javascript

Why setTimeout triggers right away instead of waiting 10000 milliseconds ? https://jsfiddle.net/gtrw3enf/8/

```
  function main(a) {
    alert(` ${a}`);
    let timeoutID;
    if (typeof main.once == 'undefined') {
      timeoutID = setInterval(loop, 5000);
    }
    
    async function loop() {
      console.log(a)
    }
  }

  main("test");
  setTimeout(main("test2"), 10000);
```

Comment: `setTimeout(() => main("test2"), 10000)`

Answer (score 1):

You're immediately calling `main` and passing the return value to [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout), when the first argument to `setTimeout` should be the function to execute after the delay.

```
setTimeout(()=>main("test2"), 10000);
```